# How to pass an array into a query string in Google App Script for a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a script that will take a query in the form of a string variable (named `sql`) and pull data from BigQuery to a Google Spreadsheet.
Something like below:

```
var sql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table";
var queryResults;

try {
var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000).setUseLegacySql(false);
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
}
```

Now, I want to create an array variable and pass it to the `sql` query string. When I pass the array as a variable like below, it didn't work: Google SpreadSheet gave me an error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: Unrecognized name: becca at [1:1088]
>   ("becca" is the first value of my array)

```
var array = ['a','b','c']
var sql = "SELECT field1 FROM UNNEST("+array+") AS field1";
```

It only worked when I manually hard code the array of strings, like below:

```
var sql = "SELECT field1 FROM UNNEST(['a','b','c']) AS field1";
```

However my array is supposed to be dynamic so manually hard coding it is not an option. How do I pass it as a variable then?

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a valid problem description. Why not show what the querystring looked like from that and other attempts, along with the relevant code snippets? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at Utilities.formatString in The documentation.

Comment: @tehhowch sorry, when I say "it didn't work", it was because Google Spreadsheet gave me an error: "GoogleJsonResponseException: Unrecognized name: becca at [1:1088]" ("becca" is the first value in my array)

Comment: @I'-'I: just tried, it still gave me the same error message: `GoogleJsonResponseException: Unrecognized name: becca at [1:1088]`

Comment: @I'-'I : yup, that works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing the array type in the string format which will create a problem. you need to convert the array variables in such array formatted string format.

```
var arrStr=arr.join("','");
"SELECT field1 FROM UNNEST(['"+arrStr+"']) AS field1"
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! You are the real MVP here!